# Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen den Adjektiven "extrovertiert" und "extravertiert"?

Tags: difference, adjective

Vor kurzem habe ich das Wort *extravertiert* gehört, das – so vermute ich – die gleiche Grundbedeutung wie *extrovertiert* hat: *nach außen gerichtet, für äußere Einflüsse leicht empfänglich.*

Gibt es einen semantischen Unterschied zwischen den beiden Adjektiven? Kann ich überall, wo ich *extrovertiert* verwende, auch *extravertiert* sagen?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Es gibt keinen Unterschied in der Bedeutung. Ursprünglich stammt der Begriff "Extraversion" aus der differentiellen Psychologie. Im wissenschaftlichen Kontext wird darum "extravertiert" verwendet. Lange Zeit stand auch nur diese Variante im Duden.

Dass sich "extrovertiert" irgendwann auch durchgesetzt hat, ist wohl auf das lateinische "intro" zurückzuführen. "intra" und "extra" sind übersetzt "innen" und "außen", aber "intro" und "extra" sind "innerhalb" und "außerhalb". Diese Unregelmäßigkeit kann man leicht übersehen und folglich "extro" verwenden, wenn auch "intro" (Introvertiertheit) im Kontext genannt wird.

Comment: Das heißt, *extro* hat sich aus einer (unnötigen?) Anpassung an *intro* ins Deutsche eingebürgert? Das lateinische *extra* wird sonst ja auch nie *extro:* Extrawurst, Extrablatt, extrazellulär ...

Comment: Es gibt aber keine Introwurst und kein Introblatt. Der Bezug fehlt also. Dagegen werden Intro- und Extravertiertheit oft in einem Atemzug genannt, man ist hier also eher geneigt "extro" zu verwenden.

Comment: Ich würde auch gerne wissen, warum es nicht *intravertiert* heißt.

Comment: Introversion kommt von intro für "innerhalb", "hineingehen" (der Fokus liegt auf der Bewegung nach innen zu) und vertere „wenden“. Also man wendet sich salopp gesagt nach innen, man geht in sich hinein. Mit "intra" funktioniert diese Bedeutung nicht, da liegt der Fokus darauf, dass man sich schon innen befindet. Man würde sich also eher in sich selbst wenden und das passt nicht so richtig. "extra" hat dagegen beide Bedeutungen. Das ist zumindest meine Vermutung zu Deiner Frage.

Answer (score 8):

Nach [Duden](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/extravertiert) werden beide Begriffe mit identischer Bedeutung eingesetzt und sind somit austauschbar.

Um zu erklären, weshalb man dennoch sowohl *extravertiert* als auch *extrovertiert* findet, muss man die Herkunft des Wortes näher betrachten.

Der Begründer der analytischen Psychologei [C. G. Jung](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Gustav_Jung) führte die folgenden psychologischen Typen eines Menschen ein:

> **introvertiert** (aus lat. *intrō* und *vertere*) ist der nach innen gekehrte Typus

und das Gegenteil

> **extravertiert** (aus lat. *extrā* und *vertere*) ist der nach außen gekehrter Typus

Im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch ist aber die grammatikalisch korrekte Variante *extravertiert* als Gegenteil von *introvertiert* zu Gunsten von *extrovertiert* verdrängt worden, wie man leicht am [Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=introvertiert,extrovertiert,extravertiert&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3) sehen kann:

[image]

Interessanterweise geht die Verwendung von *extrovertiert* mit der zunehmenden Verwendung von *introvertiert* parallel.